# Is there any sequential todo-state change for emacs org mode outlines?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In omnifocus, a project can be made sequential so that only the next task in the list appears on an agenda or within a context view. Once that single task is completed, the next task from the same list appears in view.

Is there any equivalent for emacs org? Any... like... inherited Todo-state changes?

Comment: Not sure if this fits the bill: [TODO dependencies](http://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-dependencies.html#TODO-dependencies).

Comment: "org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks" is just what I was looking for. Thank you.